# How to write a custom class for a table

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have dynamic tables in my database and I am having trouble expressing dynamic tables as a custom class. Please take a look at this class that i have created:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    private List<Column> RowColumn { get; set; } 
}

public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnType { get; set; }
    public object ColumnValue { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone see a better way to do this? This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230400/which-dbms-allows-very-large-numbers-of-tables-and-columns-per-table

Comment: What does dynamic table mean exactly?

Comment: It means that each table can have different columns and different number of rows

Comment: @Luke101: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by not having a defined database schema?  Maybe there's a better way to do this at another level than what we're looking at here.

Comment: Then why won't create a class for each table... This is what everyone on the planet do.

Comment: I will be have thousands of tables. That will be alot of work trying to create classes for each table

Comment: @gdoron makes a good point... Are you trying to write a class to handle a set of undefined tables (as I assumed, and as "dynamic table" somewhat implies) or are you trying to write a single class which handles all of your defined tables?  If the latter, why?

Comment: @Luke101: ORMs make light work of code generation.  At its simplest, you can just create a LINQ to SQL context for the whole database schema.  The number of tables won't be a performance bottleneck.  Or you could write some T4 templates to create your own.  But abstracting your database entities so that the code doesn't know which is which... seems like it's going to be more work in the long run.

Comment: @David. And I would add that thousands of tables, unless you develop an application for a bank or the American Army, is more than 50 times than I can even imagine.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a class that will handle undefined tables. This class will need to be flexible enough to handle any number columns.

Comment: @Luke101: It _really_ sounds like you're fundamentally painting yourself into a corner with this design.  If you just need a class which represents a table, why not `DataTable`?  (As Dan suggests in an answer while I type this.)  There seems to be a deeper issue here, though.  The fact that you have an undefined schema of thousands of tables is... unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need a container for dynamic table data, I'd stick with the [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class rather than write my own.

A problem I can see with your design is that you are redundantly saving the column names and types in each cell.  Depending on how big these tables are, that could be a lot of wasted memory.

It's best not to reinvent the wheel (unless it has never-before-seen features, like hover ability or something).

Comment: Whoa..you are a genius. Why didn't I think of that